# How to achieve edgy bottom of div like this image below

Tags: html, css

[image: see image]

I want to achieve this without using image slicing technique. Is it possible using CSS?

Comment: i am tempted to post an answer as this :  YES

Comment: i don't see an image?
do you tried something to achieve this?

Comment: @MihaiT never saw a better answer. =D

Comment: sorry image can be view here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yROWm.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a starting point. It's not exactly as your image, but just to show in general how it could be done :

```css
.shapeme {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid red;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:40px;
}
.shapeme:after{
    content:"";
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-top: 40px solid grey; 
    position:absolute;
    top:-50px;
    left:-100px;
}
.shapeme:before{
    content:"";
    background:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:-90px;
    height:40px;
    width:200px;
    left:-100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shapeme">

</div>
```

Comment: thanks this is helpful. would have to up this but reputation is low. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I shall give a short answer on this, but abit more abbreviated than the simple yes.

It is most definately possible, you would need to use transparency in your css.
Have a look at this link for more information.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

I would suggest that google is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;  
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```